# Error installing stringi package for OpenR

Tags: r

Platform: Linux (64-bit) 
Client tool: Rstudio and Open R 3.2.2

I am working to install stringi package for Open R 3.2.2. In order to do that i need to build "stringi" on, try fetching the latest development version of the package install string-master package first and then stringi package. This includes "ICU" data archives. I did get package from  **https://github.com/gagolews/stringi/archive/master.zip** then unzipped it and when i try to install it, it gives me error **Error in rawToChar(block[seq_len(ns)})**.

Then, when i try to install "stringi" package version 1.1.2 from **rstudio** client, it seems get installed successfully but when i try to attach it using code **library("stringi")**

Thank you,